# c# Label Text Databinding does not refresh Text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have Label databound with BindingSource property. Label.Text property get updated only once.

this is how is property bound to label

`this.lblWorkPlace.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.appStateBindingSource, "ResourceName", true));`

i also tried to bind same property to textbox and textbox updates properly

`this.lTextEdit1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.appStateBindingSource, "ResourceName", true));`

what could be wrong?

UPDATE

this is my "state" class

```
public class AppState: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private static Operation _activeTask;


    private static AppState _instance;


    public static AppState Instance
    {
        get => _instance ?? (_instance = new AppState());
    }


    public Operation ActiveTask
    {
        get => _activeTask;
        set
        {
            if (value != _activeTask)
            {
                _activeTask = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ResourceName");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

    public string ResourceName => ActiveTask?.Operacija?.acResursName.Trim() ?? "";
}


}
```

Comment: How do you expect the labels text to get updated, are you using this in a loop?

Comment: Where's the code for the property that feeds this binding? Also, you might want to add `DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged` as the final parameter in the DataBindings.

Comment: i would like that label get updated when property text changed, because text field get updated but label dont

Comment: It works the same way for `Label` and `TextBox` without ant problem. (And you probably know the `ActiveTask` property of the is `AppState` instance is null at first and as soon as you assign an `Operation` to the property, label/text box will get updated.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was cross thread call. Application did not update UI and did not throw any exceptions